# CakePHP localization not working for core messages

Tags: cakephp, localization

I've followed the official [Internationalization & Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) guide and I got all my site-specific messages translated as expected.

However for some reason the core CakePHP messages are not translated/localized, e.g. AuthComponent message "You are not authorized to access that location." is still displayed in English when my custom messages are translated to Polish according to the default.po file definition.

Comment: If you have comments you should add them to your question.

Comment: @pinckerman - I've added a valid answer to this question and deleted my lengthy comment to increase S/N ratio. Hope it helps someone. BTW: even though it is purely virtual it still hurts to get a downvote. :-(

Comment: I know, I rarely downvote people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for it didn't work was that I combined default.po and core.po file contents into one file: default.po. I simply didn't get it that those two files shall be kept separate. After I split translation into default.po (my custom messages) and core.po (core CakePHP messages) it all started to work flawlessly as expected.

Cake Book mentions this however it was not clear to me right from the start:

> CakePHP will look for your po files in the following location:
>
> `/app/Locale/<locale>/LC_MESSAGES/<domain>.po`

The default domain is ‘default’, therefore your locale folder should look something like this (sample valid for French localization):

```
 /app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/core.po
 /app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
```

I am posting this answer to hopefully help fellow programmers out there. :-)